# I need to map through json

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import {
    fetchSongs
} from '../store/actions';

const MainPage = ({songsData, fetchSongs}) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchSongs()
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className='songs'>
            <ul>
                {
                    Object.keys(songsData.songs).map(song =>
                        <li>{song.toptracks.track.name}</li>
                    )
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        songsData: state.songs
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchSongs: () => dispatch(fetchSongs())
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainPage);
```

this is my component. Here I have to get the data. It seems to me that I need to convert it into array but don't know how to do it. I've tried Object.values, Object.keys but it doesn't work.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined or 'map' is not a function

below is part of my json:

> {"toptracks":{"track":[{"name":"Believe","playcount":"2750126","listeners":"536950","mbid":"32ca187e-ee25-4f18-b7d0-3b6713f24635","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Cher/_/Believe","streamable":"0","artist":{"name":"Cher","mbid":"bfcc6d75-a6a5-4bc6-8282-47aec8531818","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Cher"},"image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/34s/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/64s/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/174s/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/`enter code here`i/u/300x300/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png","size":"extralarge"}],"@attr":{"rank":"1"}}

import * as actionTypes from './../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
loading: false,
songs: [],
error: ''
}

reducer below:

```
export const songsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.FETCH_SONG_REQUEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        case actionTypes.FETCH_SONG_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                songs: action.payload,
                error: ''
            }
        case actionTypes.FETCH_SONG_FAILURE:
            return {
                loading: false,
                songs: [],
                error: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

it's action:

```
import axios from 'axios';

import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';

export const fetchSongRequest = () => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.FETCH_SONG_REQUEST
    }
}

export const fetchSongSuccess = (songs) => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.FETCH_SONG_SUCCESS,
        payload: songs
    }
}

export const fetchSongFailure = (error) => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.FETCH_SONG_FAILURE,
        payload: error
    }
}

export const fetchSongs = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(fetchSongRequest)
        axios
            .get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettoptracks&artist=cher&api_key=c17b1886d9465542a9cd32437c804db6&format=json')
            .then(response => {
                const songs = response.data;
                dispatch(fetchSongSuccess(songs))
            })
            .catch(error => {
                const errorMsg = error.message;
                dispatch(fetchSongFailure(errorMsg))
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. The provided JSON is not complete.
2. Which variable actually holds the provided JSON ? Is it `songsData.songs` ?

Comment: It's part of the json because it is to long. And yes, songsData.songs holds the json

Comment: http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettoptracks&artist=cher&api_key=c17b1886d9465542a9cd32437c804db6&format=json

Comment: above is the linl to json

Comment: can you include  the reducer that holds songData? maybe it throws an error on the first render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.keys(songsData.songs).map()` is uncessary.
From the JSON, We can see that the array we want to iterate over is `songsData.songs.toptracks.track`.

Also, in the state, `songs` is initialised as an empty array. But event `FETCH_SONG_SUCCESS` changes `songs` to be an object. It should ideally be initialised as `songs: {}` in the `initialState`

And for initial render - where `songs` is still empty, it does not have property `toptracks` on it. So we have to make sure `songsData.songs.toptracks` is truthy before we actually access and iterate over `songsData.songs.toptracks.track`.

Here is the snippet that should do the job:

```
<ul>
  {songsData.songs.toptracks &&
    songsData.songs.toptracks.track.map((aTrack) => <li>{aTrack.name}</li>)}
</ul>
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'track' of undefined

Comment: That means that `songsData.songs` does not contain `toptracks` as key - ( which I tried to confirm ). Can you `console.log(songsData)` and see what comes up ?

Comment: it works! what's the difference? Why should it contain songsData.songs.toptracks &&?

Comment: I have updated the answer, Glad I was able to help!